# How i can solve Electron error: "Buffer is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, electron, add-on

I am developing an application on emberjs and using electron for the desktop version.

I connected the eosjs-ecc addon and looking at its sources I realized that it uses Buffer, but this error "Buffer is not defined" occurs.

I tried several options among which
`webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }`
and that didn't help either.

Someone solved a similar problem? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Buffer` isn't available on the web, you need to polyfill it.

And since modern ember uses webpack, polyfilling `Buffer` is well documented. Here is a [list of plugins](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#nodesourceplugin) webpack provides out of the box.

If you're only using ember-auto-import, in your ember-cli-build.js, you'd provide your webpack config like this:

```js
// ember-cli-build.js

// ...

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  // ...
  autoImport: {
    webpack: {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
      ],
    }
  }
});
```

or if you're using embroider, you'd configure webpack this way:

```js
// ember-cli-build.js

const { Webpack } = require('@embroider/webpack');
return require('@embroider/compat').compatBuild(app, Webpack, {
  packagerOptions: {
    webpackConfig: {
     plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
      ],
    }
  }
});
```